# static objects / multiple app domains / one process

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, process, appdomain

Ok here is the problem, I have a winform application that relies heavily on static variables and it being a singleton application (only one instance of the process at a time).

I now need to create a wrapping application that would create say 6 of those winform applications and switch between their primary windows. The reason for doing it this way, is that these applications have a lot of static references that must be updated depending on what database they are connected to. Our users need to connect to several databases now and re-engineering the code to get rid of the static issues is NOT an option.

So my question is this, I know I can create new app domains in one process, but do each of those app domains get a new set of static references? Or do I actually have to have separate processes? If so, how could I go about building an new application that would create 6 instances of the old application and communicate data to each one of them (things like Hide/Show, load this object, query this database, etc...) Looking for something simple as this is going to end up being a throw away project.

Thanks!

Comment: "Our users need [this] now" and "this is going to end up being a throw away project" seem contradictory.

Comment: Yes it does seem so. They need it for this temporary project, the amount of time it would take to fix all the static reference issues FAR outweighs the temporary benefit. After our testing phase is complete, this will all be thrown out. This is really a work around that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Each app domain has its own set of loaded assemblies (except [domain-neutral assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43wc4hhs.aspx), which are shared between domain) and types. Each type in the app domain has it's own instances of static variables (in case of domain-neutral assemblies CLR provides this in special way).

Comment: Not totally correct. Assemblies can be shared accross AppDomains. The CLR does add some code for statics to isolate the statics between AppDomains which make static variables a little slower when multiple appdomains are involved.

Comment: @AloisKraus: good remark, +1. But, I hope, this is not actual for topic starter. Anyway, I've updated the answer.